# Arduino and writing file to SD

Tags: arduino

I have the following code

global

```
File logFile
```

and inside loop()

```
DateTime now = rtc.now();
String stringFilename = "";
stringFilename = String(now.year())+"_"+String(now.month())+"_"+String(now.day());
stringFilename += ".csv";
Serial.println(stringFilename);
char filename[stringFilename.length() + 1];
stringFilename.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));
String dataString = "";
dataString += String(now.year());
Serial.print("Filename: ");
Serial.println(filename);
if (!SD.exists(filename)){
  Serial.println("File does not exist");
  logFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
}
if (logFile){
    logFile.println(dataString);
}else{
    Serial.println("Could not open file");
}
```

Filename is something like 2014_5_26.csv. SD empty. The above code won't open file for writing. If I substitute filename with a literal like "datalog.txt" it works. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I got what my problem was. The name was to long. It can be only up to 8 characters. Can I ask something different? Can I call SD.begin(chipSelect) in loop to determine if SD is present or is this called always on setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in loop but the program speed will be reduce.
Don't forget to close your file (`SD.close()`) before to be sure that your data are correctly written to the SD card

Comment: Are you sure? http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=46969.0 says that I cannot call begin repeatedly

Comment: I use this method since a very long time and I haven't got any problem. My SDCard is still in good condition and without bad block and my SDShield is still working (more than 7 months this day).
But you have to close all connection before

Comment: Could you provide me with some sample code? Also there is no SD.close() in Arduino's reference about the SD library here(http://goo.gl/TKg15c). Do u mean maybe File's close() method?

Answer (score 0):

8.3 filename rules may apply. Your Date derived ("2014_5_26") filename appears to have 9 characters. When you use "datalog", that has 8 characters, it works.